# Determining if an object is a Map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, instanceof, typeof

I am writing a function that returns `true` if the argument passed to it is an instance of a JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

As you may have guessed `typeof new Map()` returns the string `object` and we don't get a handy `Map.isMap` method.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function isMap(v) {
  return typeof Map !== 'undefined' &&
    // gaurd for maps that were created in another window context
    Map.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Map]' ||
    // gaurd against toString being overridden
    v instanceof Map;
}

(function test() {
  const map = new Map();

  write(isMap(map));

  Map.prototype.toString = function myToString() {
    return 'something else';
  };

  write(isMap(map));
}());

function write(value) {
  document.write(`${value}<br />`);
}
```

So far so good, but when testing maps between frames and when `toString()` has been overridden, `isMap` fails ([I do understand why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_context_(e.g._frames_or_windows))).

For Example:

```
<iframe id="testFrame"></iframe>
<script>
  const testWindow = document.querySelector('#testFrame').contentWindow;
  // false when toString is overridden 
  write(isMap(new testWindow.Map())); 
</script>
```

[Here is a full Code Pen Demonstrating the issue](https://codepen.io/robbmj/pen/QKmoYE?editors=0000)

Is there a way to write the `isMap` function so that it will return `true` 
when both `toString` is overridden and the map object originates from another frame?

Comment: @Bergi, how is this a duplicate? Your answer advocates using `instanceof` my question states the issue I am having with `instanceof` also the internal method you are checking on the set, does not apply to the `Map` prototype (i think).

Comment: It's exactly the same for sets and maps. I guess I'll better edit the answer to be canonical.

Comment: @Bergi please see the above edit, to my comment.

Comment: See [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29926193/revisions) there :-) You can use the other approaches if you don't like `instanceof` - and supporting `Map` instead of `Set` is just a choice of the right name.

Comment: Note, this question is being discussed on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336008/215552).

Answer (score 5):

You can check `Object.prototype.toString.call(new testWindow.Map)`.

If that has been overridden, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't though of that. I guess it does add one extra step of certainty.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `toString` being overridden (you can cache it if you come first), but rather about `Symbol.toStringTag`.